# react-map-gl custom markers don't stay at exact position on zoom

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I'm working to load a Mapbox map using Uber's react-map-gl library. I have successfully loaded the map with custom markers via JSON served from my API (as you can see from this first image).

[image: mapbox]

If you look at the green marker near Houston though, it's off somewhere in the Gulf of Mexico for some reason. However if I zoom into that area...

[image: zoomed in mapbox]

You can see that as I zoom in, the marker readjusts to its correct position. What would cause something like this?

```
import ReactMapGL, { Marker, NavigationControl, Popup } from 'react-map-gl';
import CityInfo from './city-info';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';

class ExplorePage extends Component {
    state = {
        viewport: {
            width    : 400,
            height   : 400,
            latitude : 38.789093,
            longitude: -95.295881,
            zoom     : 3.7,
        },
        popupInfo: null,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(explorepageActions.getFavoriteHikes());
    }

    _renderMarker = (marker, index) => {
        return (
            <Marker
                anchor='bottom'
                key={`marker-${index}`}
                longitude={parseFloat(marker.longitude)}
                latitude={parseFloat(marker.latitude)}
            >
                <Pin width={100} onClick={(event) => this._handleClick(event, marker)} />
        </Marker>
        );
    };

    _onViewportChange = viewport => this.setState({viewport});

    render() {
    const { explorepageData, loading } = this.props;
    const { viewport } = this.state;

    return (
        <ExplorePageStyles>
            {loading && <img src='/static/loading.svg' alt='loading' className='loading-img' />}
            {explorepageData.data &&
            <Fragment>
                <Sidebar>
                    <ExploreSidebar favoriteHikes={explorepageData} />
                </Sidebar>
                <ReactMapGL
                    {...viewport}
                    mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
                    width='100%'
                    height='100%'
                    style={{ float: 'right' }}
                    onViewportChange={this._onViewportChange}
                    attributionControl={false}
                >
                    {explorepageData.data.map(this._renderMarker)}
                    {this._renderPopup()}
                    <div className="nav" style={navStyle}>
                        <NavigationControl />
                    </div>
                </ReactMapGL>
            </Fragment>
            }
        </ExplorePageStyles>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok after a few days of messing around I finally figured it out. The issue had something to do with my use of a custom icon for the Marker. Copying over the [example's pin](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl/blob/4.0-release/examples/controls/src/city-pin.js) made it work correctly.

Comment: Hi! I had that behavior on mobile devices. In my case I accidentally commented out `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`. After I uncommented this meta tag, all my pins started works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Including the css file fixed this issue for me

```
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css'
```

Answer (score 3):

Found one more solution:

```
let size = 40;

{cities.map(({ coordinates }) => (
  <Marker
    latitude={coordinates.latitude}
    longitude={coordinates.longitude}
  >
    <div
      style={{ transform: `translate(${-size / 2}px,${-size}px)` }}
      onClick={(e) => {
        setSelectedCity(coordinates);
      }}
    >
      <img
        src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/location.svg'}
        alt="Location-icon"
      />
    </div>
  </Marker>
))}
```

Most important here is :

`` style={{ transform: `translate(${-size / 2}px,${-size}px)\` }} ``

Answer (score 2):

because your latitude and longitude is change every time when you scrolling

```
const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
  width: '100%',
  height: 240,
  latitude: 41.70123,
  longitude: 44.85137,
  zoom: 17,
  mapboxApiAccessToken: process.env.MAP_ACCESS_TOKEN
})

const [marker] = useState({
  latitude: 41.70123,
  longitude: 44.85137
})

<ReactMapGL className="map" {...viewport} onViewportChange={listenViewportChange}
>
  <Marker {...marker}>
    <img src={mapPingIcon} alt="" />
  </Marker>
</ReactMapGL>
```